# How to combine 3 change events to hide a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, blur

I am trying to hide a div when multiple different options are chosen. I have the below for the first button element but I am trying to figure out how to expand this out into 3 elements needing to be changed in order to change a separate div. Thank you for the help:

```
$('#Choice').change(function() {
    var choice = $(this).val();
    var myDiv = $('#myDivArea');
    
    if(choice == 'Option 1'){  
      myDiv.show().blur().change();  
    } else {  
      myDiv.hide().blur().change();  
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

very ugly code but working :)
With 4 parameters, you must read about xor

js

```
var choice1 = $('#a').val()
var choice2 = $('#b').val()
var choice3 = $('#c').val()

var myDiv = $('#myDivArea');
$('input').on('input', function(){ 
  if( ($('#a').val() == $('#b').val()) && ($('#b').val() == $('#c').val()) )
  {  
    myDiv.show(); 
  
  } 
  else 
  {  
    myDiv.hide();  
  }
} )
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
<input type="text" id="c">
<div id="myDivArea" > test </div>
```